# Can compensation income from an employee stock purchase plan be negative?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-loss, espp

If I took a loss on my sale of stock from an ESPP (employee stock purchase plan), and the stock had a qualifying disposition, what is my compensation income?

I found the following definition:

> In a qualifying disposition, your compensation income is equal to the
>   difference between what you paid for the shares and what you sold them
>   for or the discount (difference between what you would have paid for
>   the shares and what they were worth) on the grant date, whichever is
>   lower.

Given that what I paid for the shares and what I sold them for is a loss (a negative number, which will always be less than the amount of the discount), is my compensation income zero or negative? Am I interpreting this wrong?

This is the United States.

Comment: Since you are asking about taxes, you must specify a country. Please edit your question and add the corresponding country tag.

Comment: This is for America. I edited the question. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence you quoted does not apply in the case where you sell the stock at a loss. In that case, you recognize zero ordinary income, and a capital loss (opposite of a gain) for the loss.

Reference: http://efs.fidelity.com/support/sps/article/article2.html